# Как из потока передать основному окну сообщение?

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня есть приложение, в котором открывается поток.

Как из потока передать основному окну сообщение? Например, какие-то вычисленные данные или текст?

Answer (score 2):

Вам поможет функция [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), для передачи сообщения нужно знать хендл окна. Хотя не очень понятно, зачем это все, у вас же все в одном приложении происходит. Есть и другие методы (функции), если опишите подробнее, что надо сделать, может что еще подсказать можно будет.

Comment: Запускаю поток так:

std::thread potok_ (klient, &база_Kient_mob, hWnd);
klient.detach ();//отсоединение потока из него надо передать сообщение или данные

Comment: ну тогда вам нужно использовать `SendMessage` с типом сообщения  [WM_COPYDATA message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), примеры есть на MSDN

Comment: @ЮрийПикин, а вообще вы что хотите, передать ДАННЫЕ, или информацию о том, что вычисления окончены и данные можно забрать? Просто если второй вариант, то определите свой тип сообщения, а сами данные передавайте уже через какую-нибудь глобальную переменную или как-нибудь еще, так быстрее будет. Просто внутри одного процесса передавать ДАННЫЕ через сообщения это изврат.

Answer (score 1):

Используй синхронную посылку сообщений `SendMessage/SendDlgItemMessage`, только не забывай если окно которому посылаешь сообщение будет занято обработкой данных или другим ожиданием, то поток так же повиснет на это время, вот для этого есть такие функции. `SendMessageTimeout`, `SendMessageCallback`, `SendNotifyMessage`, только `PostMessage` не используй.

Comment: >только PostMessage не используй.

почему?

Comment: @zenden2k, для передачи данных используется сообщение WM_COPYDATA, а этот тип сообщения нельзя отправить с помощью `PostMessage`, в документации расписано подробнее, почему

Comment: @Flowneee, сообщение WM_COPYDATA предназначено для передачи данных между процессами. Здесь же идет речь о передаче данных между потоками одного процесса.

Comment: @zenden2k автор вопроса спрашивал именно про передачу ДАННЫХ, хотя я сразу не понял, зачем использовать сообщения для передачи данных внутри одного процесса. Если использовать сообщения как механизм СИНХРОНИЗАЦИИ, то тогда `PostMessage` лучше не использовать, так как сообщение будет поставлено в очередь, тогда как после `SendMessage` сообщение будет обработано вне очереди.

Answer (score 0):

В winapi вы можете обращаться к окнам из любого потока. Так что можно просто использовать `SetWindowText` или `SendMessage`.

Comment: я отправляю сообщение так: SendMessage (FindWindow (NULL, _T ("Сервер 3.01")), WM_SETTEXT, 0, (long int)"Новый текст\0"); а как его принять? что то ничено не нашел...

Comment: @ЮрийПикин, WM_SETTEXT не надо отправлять вручную.
Например, у вас есть контрол `Edit` (поле ввода) и вы хотите туда вывести текст. Тогда вызывайте `SetWindowText(hwndEdit, "Новый текст");`

Если же вы хотите послать сообщение и самостоятельно обрабатывать его в основном потоке, сделайте `#define WM_MYMESSAGE  (WM_USER + 111)` (любое число), и отправляйте через `SendMessage`, а принимайте в оконной процедуре (WindowProc), или если вы используете какой-то фреймворк (например MFC), то смотрите в документации по нему.