# Как вызвать PostQuitMessage из другого потока?

Tags: windows, многопоточность, winapi

Есть приложение Windows. Оно создаёт второй поток и в этом втором потоке мы в какой-то момент времени осознаём, что хотим закрыть приложение. Закрытие инициируется событием WM_QIUT, но напрямую это событие посылать нельзя - нужно вызвать функцию PostQuitMessage. Причём эта функция не принимает никаких аргументов, позволяющих указать какое окно или поток мы хотим закрыть - она закрывает окно связанное с потоком из которого она была вызвана. Если мы вызываем эту функцию из второго потока то ничего не происходит.

Подскажите пожалуйста - есть ли какой-нибудь простой способ инициировать закрытие приложения из второго потока? Может быть есть какой-то наиболее общепринятый способ?

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2942841/4928642 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432397/178988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании второго потока просто передайте ему хендл главного окна приложения.
Когда этому потоку необходимо будет инициировать завершение приложения, имея хендл главного окна, можно сделать это любым доступным способом (вызов функции DestroyWindow(), отправка условного пользовательского сообщения окну через PostMessage(), отправка одного из системных сообщений и т.д.) - в зависимости от того, какую последовательность событий требуется обеспечить при закрытии приложения.